# From a set of list make subsets of order 3 of those list

Tags: python-3.x, list, set

I have the following lists:

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [1,2,3]
l3 = [1,2,5]
l4 = [1,3,5]
l5 = [1,2,5]
l6 = [2,4,5]
l7 = [2,3,4]
l8 = [3,4,5]
l9 = [3,4,5]
l10 = [1,3,4]
l11 = [2,3,5]
l12 = [1,4,5]
```

Let `s` be the following set

```
s = {l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8, l9, l10, l11, l12}
```

I am willing to print subsets of order 3 of `s`(as a list), that is

```
input:  s = {l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8, l9, l10, l11, l12}, n = 3
output: [{l1,l2,l3}, {l1,l2,l4}, {l1,l2,l5},...]
```

Naively, I have tried the following

```
import itertools 

def findsubsets(s, n): 
    return list(itertools.combinations(s, n)) 

s = {l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8, l9, l10, l11, l12} 
n = 3

print(findsubsets(s, n))
```

But got the error:

```
    s = {l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8, l9, l10, l11, l12} 
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: It's  Because Sets require their items to be hashable.  and List is not hashable. You could change it to `list_of_list = [l1, l2, l3.... ]` instead.

Comment: @DanielHao, thank you for solving the issue for me.